# Formulation of a recursive solution (variable for loops)

Tags: python, recursion, for-loop

Please consider the below algorithm:

```
  for(j1 = n upto 0)
     for(j2 = n-j1 upto 0)
       for(j3 = n-j1-j2 upto 0)
        .
         .
           for (jmax = n -j1 - j2 - j_(max-1))
            {
             count++;
             product.append(j1 * j2 ... jmax); // just an example
            }
```

As you can see, some relevant points about the algo snippet above:

1. I have listed an algorithm with a variable number of for loops.
2. The result that i calculate at each innermost loop is appended to a list. This list will grow to dimension of 'count'.

Is this problem a suitable candidate for recursion? If yes, i am really not sure how to break the problem up. I am trying to code this up in python, and i do not expect any code from you guys. Just some pointers or examples in the right direction. Thank you.

Here is an initial try for a sample case http://pastebin.com/PiLNTWED

Comment: It seems like having a function that does one loop and then calls itself to do the the inner loops would be the most straightforward.

Comment: [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is finding all the `m`-tuples (`m` being the `max` subscript of `j` from your pseudocode) of non-negative integers that add up to `n` or less. In Python, the most natural way of expressing that would be with a recursive generator:

```
def gen_tuples(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        yield ()
    else:
        for x in range(n, -1, -1):
            for sub_result in gen_tuples(m-1, n-x):
                yield (x,)+sub_result
```

Example output:

```
>>> for x, y, z in gen_sums(3, 3):
    print(x, y, z)

3 0 0
2 1 0
2 0 1
2 0 0
1 2 0
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 2
1 0 1
1 0 0
0 3 0
0 2 1
0 2 0
0 1 2
0 1 1
0 1 0
0 0 3
0 0 2
0 0 1
0 0 0
```

Comment: thanks for the example, although i need something different. To see the contrast and be more explicative, An output of my code and output as an answer below.

Comment: @MhAcKNI: Oh, you want the tuples to add up to exactly `n`, rather than `n` or less. That was actually what I implemented first, before editing to match the loop you have in your question. To get what you want, modify the base case of my code to be `if m == 1: yield (n,)`

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using permutations, combinations or product from the *itertools* module.
If you want all the possible combinations of i, j, k, ... (i.e. nested for loops)
you can use:

```
for p in product(range(n), repeat=depth):
    j1, j2, j3, ... = p # the same as nested for loops
    # do stuff here
```

But beware, the number of iterations in the loop grows exponentially!

Comment: the number of iterations wont be a constraint. i m trying to solve this. will post updates soon.

Comment: Here is a simple case when i know the depth [simple example code](http://pastebin.com/PiLNTWED). Now i m not sure how i could translate that into itertools when i dont know the depth.

Answer (score 0):

the toy example will translate into a kind of tail recursion so, personally, i wouldn't expect  a recursive version to be more insightful for code review and maintenance.

however, to get acquainted to the principle, attempt to factor out the invariant parts / common terms from the individual loop and try to identify a pattern (and best prove it afterwards!). you should be able to fix a signature of the recursive procedure to be written. flesh it out with the parts inherent to the loop body/ies (and don't forget the termination condition).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you want to transform `for` loops into recursive calls, you will need to replace the `for` statements with `if` statements. For nested loops, you will transform these into function calls.

For practice, start with a dumb translation of the code that works and then attempt to see where you can optimize later.

To give you an idea to try to apply to your situation, I would translate something like this:

```
results = []
for i in range(n):
    results.append(do_stuff(i, n))
```

to something like this:

```
results = []

def loop(n, results, i=0):
    if i >= n:
        return results
    results.append(do_stuff(i, n))
    i += 1
    loop(n, results, i)
```

there are different ways to handle returning the results list, but you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: The thing is that i do not know 'n'. Second, the loop variable for ith loop depends upon the previous (i-1)th loop and so on.

Answer (score 0):

-- As a response to the excellent listing by Blckgnht -- Consider here the case of n = 2 and max = 3

```
def simpletest():    

    '''
    I am going to just test the algo listing with assumption
    degree n = 2
    max = dim(m_p(n-1)) = 3, 
    so j1 j2 and upto j3 are required for every entry into m_p(degree2)
    Lets just print j1,j2,j3 to verify if the function
    works in other general version where the number of for loops is not known
    '''
    n = 2
    count = 0
    for j1 in range(n, -1, -1):
        for j2 in range(n -j1, -1, -1):
            j3 = (n-(j1+j2)) 
            count = count + 1
            print 'To calculate m_p(%d)[%d], j1,j2,j3 = ' %(n,count), j1, j2, j3

    assert(count==6)        # just a checkpoint. See P.169 for a proof
    print 'No. of entries =', count
```

The output of this code (and it is correct).

```
    In [54]: %run _myCode/Python/invariant_hack.py
To calculate m_p(2)[1], j1,j2,j3 =  2 0 0
To calculate m_p(2)[2], j1,j2,j3 =  1 1 0
To calculate m_p(2)[3], j1,j2,j3 =  1 0 1
To calculate m_p(2)[4], j1,j2,j3 =  0 2 0
To calculate m_p(2)[5], j1,j2,j3 =  0 1 1
To calculate m_p(2)[6], j1,j2,j3 =  0 0 2
No. of entries = 6
```